# to change the value of an element of an array by using the index ref in perl

Tags: perl

```
 #!/bin/usr/perl -w
 use strict;
 print "Enter your input filename for original  sample data values: \n";
 chomp($data=<STDIN>);
 print "Enter your input filename for adjustment values\n";
 chomp($adj=<STDIN>) ;
 print "Enter your output filename for resultant adjusted new sample data \n";
 chomp($new=<STDIN>);
 open(R1,"$data") or die("error");
 open(R2,"$adj") or die ("error");
 open(WW,"+>$new") or die ("error");
 while( ($line1=(<R1>)) && ($line2=(<R2>)) )
 {
 $l1=$line1;
 @arr1= split(" ",$l1);
 $l2=$line2;
 @arr2= split(" ",$l2);
 $l= ( scalar@arr1); 
 $p= (scalar@arr2);

 for ( $i = 0; $i <= $l; $i++ ){
    for ( $j =($i+1); $j <= $l; $j++ ){

        if ($arr1[$i]< $arr1[$j]){
            $a = $arr1[$i] + ($arr2[$i]/2);
            $b = $arr1[$j] - ($arr2[$i]/2);
            push ( $arr1[$i]->$a , $arr1[$j]->$b);

        }
        elsif ( $arr1[$i]= $arr1[$j]){
            $a = $arr1[$i];
        $b = $arr1[$j];
            push ($arr1[$i]->$a,$arr1[$j]->$b);

        }      
        else{
            $a = $arr1[$i]-($arr2[$i]/2);
        $b = $arr1[$j]+ ($arr2[$i]/2);
        push ($arr1[$i]->$a,$arr1[$j]->$b);

        }
    }

 }
 $l1 = scalar@arr1;
 for ($k = 0; $k <= $l1 ; $k++)
 {
 if (($k % 10) != 0){
    print  WW "$arr1[$k]"; 
    print  WW "\t" ;
}
else {
    print WW "\n";
    print WW "$arr1[$k]";
    print WW "\t";
}

 }


 }
 close(R1);
 close(R2);
 close(WW);


 exit;
```

when i am running this prog. i am getting an error that "not an ARRAY reference at line 29".
how can i create the reference to my first array `@arr1` ??? so that it stores the changed values of the element at the particular index after running the iteration.

input :

```
@array1  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  

@array2  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

desired output

```
@array1  
15 1.5 2 3 6 4 11.5 5 5.5
```

Comment: can anyone please help me with this

Comment: `push ( $arr1[$i]->$a , $arr1[$j]->$b);`
What are you trying to do in this line?

Comment: i want to store the value of variable a and b at that particular index of @arr1

Comment: `$arr1[$i] = $a; `
`$arr1[$j] = $b;`

This will overwrite the old values in the specific indexes

Comment: it is again giving the same error " not an ARRAY reference "

Comment: @user3483833 Your first problem is that you aren't actually utilizing [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).  You include it at the top of your script, but not a single variable is declared with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) and therefore the script will not actually run unless you're just commenting out that line.  Fix this first and then we might be able to help you more.

Comment: no i have used it my prog .. might be got deleted in the editing .. can you help with my programme please

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not getting the answer you say you're looking for, but what it appears you're trying to do is to store the value of $a into the $i'th index of array @arr1 and the value of $b into the $jth index of @arr1.  I have hoisted the assignment code out of the if branches since it will be the same for all three cases.  I have also fixed a subtle error you had in your conditions.  You had

```
elsif ( $arr1[$i]= $arr1[$j]){
```

but you surely meant to do an equality comparison rather than an assignment here:

```
elsif ( $arr1[$i] == $arr1[$j]){
```

So here is the modified section.  As I say, it still doesn't print out what you say the desired result is, and I'm not sure whether it's because your computation is wrong or your printing is wrong (I couldn't figure out any obvious transform from your inputs to your desired output), but this should at least put you in the right direction:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= $l; $i++ ){
    for ( $j =($i+1); $j <= $l; $j++ ){

        if ($arr1[$i]< $arr1[$j]){
            $a = $arr1[$i] + ($arr2[$i]/2);
            $b = $arr1[$j] - ($arr2[$i]/2);
#            push ( $arr1[$i]->$a , $arr1[$j]->$b);

        }
        elsif ( $arr1[$i] == $arr1[$j]){
            $a = $arr1[$i];
            $b = $arr1[$j];
#            push ($arr1[$i]->$a,$arr1[$j]->$b);

        }      
        else{
            $a = $arr1[$i]-($arr2[$i]/2);
            $b = $arr1[$j]+ ($arr2[$i]/2);
#        push ($arr1[$i]->$a,$arr1[$j]->$b);

        }
        $arr1[$i] = $a;
        $arr1[$j] = $b;
    }

}
```